# How can I troubleshoot ssh further?

Tags: bash, ssh

I get thins error some times:

```
Bobst-LL2-iMac-16:~ nyu$ ssh foo@foo.com -v -v -v
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to arcmarks.com [107.180.41.42] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/nyu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nyu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nyu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nyu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I know that my server is setup correctly b.c. I can always connect from my personal computer.  I think it is the way the client machine at the library is setup. The only configuration files I gound were at

```
/etc

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  3957 Aug 22 15:14 ssh_config
-rw-------  1 root  wheel   668 Aug 23 00:00 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   590 Aug 23 00:00 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------  1 root  wheel   965 Aug 23 00:00 ssh_host_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   630 Aug 23 00:00 ssh_host_key.pub
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  1675 Aug 23 00:00 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   382 Aug 23 00:00 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  4161 Aug 22 15:14 sshd_config
```

but it does not matter b.c. I do not have write access to any of them.  How can I troubleshoot this issue further?  I've already verified ssh works from my personal computer.

Interestingly, if I simply generate and ssh public/private key pair on the client I get the new error:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to foo.com [107.180.41.42] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/nyu/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/nyu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/nyu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nyu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nyu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peerv
```

Comment: A question about using ssh as an end-user is not a question about programming. StackOverflow is specifically focused around questions about code. Consider http://superuser.com/?

Comment: This connection is coming from your machine on a library network or a library machine itself? `Connection reset by peer` is a networking issue. What do the logs on the server itself say (they are almost always more useful for actual ssh problems though this doesn't look like it is one).

Comment: @Etan- I'm on a shared linux box with a cpanel interface.  What logs would you like me to look at?

Comment: The other log is still same. If you have access to `/var/log` on server, there should be `secure` or `auth.log` or similar where should be logged some failure.

Comment: I just checked and I don't see a `var` folder, I do have a `logs` folder but it just has a zipped file in it from yesterday.  The error was today however.

Comment: You don't have a `/var` folder? But you do have a `/logs` folder? That doesn't sound like a normal system (or that you have access to the actual root filesystem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple `-v`s (e.g.: `-v -v -v`):

```
-v   Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its
     progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentica-
     tion, and configuration problems.

     Multiple -v options increase the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case though, it did not change much.

Comment: and to be concise use `-vvv`